# LINQ Query in VB.net comparing integers

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to write a LINQ query that compares an integer value in a database to an integer variable.  This is not working.  I can compare text values but comparing integers returns a null.

```
        Private Sub txtRoomNum_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtRoomNum.TextChanged
    If Val(txtRoomNum.Text) > 99 Then
        Dim intRoomNum As Integer

        intRoomNum = Val(txtRoomNum.Text)
        Dim RoomData = (From Rooms In BadermanIslandDataSet.Rooms
                        Where Rooms.HotelID = intHotelID).SingleOrDefault
        ''Where Rooms.HotelID = intHotelID And Rooms.RoomNumber = intRoomNum
        Try
            txtTest.Text = RoomData.RoomID
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtTest.Text = "null"
        End Try
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  `intRoomNum = Val(txtRoomNum.Text)` is assigning a Double to an integer

Comment: My trouble is in the query itself.  The current form of it is comparing Rooms.HotelID to intHotelID.  This is giving me a Null value.  I have tried putting in a number directly and it still doesn’t work.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict and you will discover more troubles

Answer (score 0):

Change `txtTest.Text = RoomData.RoomID`

to `Convert.ToInt32(txtTest.Text) = RoomData.RoomID)`

You were comparing `string` and `integer` before

Answer (score 0):

Since it's user input I would try using Integer.TryParse when getting the value from the text field. This will prevent an exception from being raised, and in the case the parse fails you can ask your user to only use a number in that field.

```
If Integer.TryParse(txtRoomNum.Text, intRoomNum) Then
   ...your logic
Else
   ...something to let them know to only put a number in txtRoomNum.Text
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue.  I needed a RoomsBindingSource on the form.  Once that was added it worked like a champ.

Comment: Well, it sort’a works.  If I am looking for a room in hotel 1 it works, otherwise it doesn’t.  Current code looks like this…

Comment: Dim intRoomNum As Integer

        If Int32.TryParse(txtRoomNum.Text, intRoomNum) Then
            If intRoomNum > 99 Then
                Try
                    Dim RoomInfo = (From Rooms In BadermanIslandDataSet.Rooms
                                    Where Rooms.HotelID = intHotelID And Rooms.RoomNumber = intRoomNum
                                    Select Rooms.RoomID)
                    intRoomID = RoomInfo.First
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
                txtTest.Text = intRoomID
            End If
        Else

        End If